# Checked attribute on List element HTML

Tags: html, css

I was reading about HTML5 and i came across with this simple example. I cant understand how the li tag can take a checked attribute without any errors in browsers?

The only elements that could take checked attributes are the ones for example radio group buttons or select elements.

Where can I find out which attributes a specific element can take?

```html
<ul id="group1" class="radiogroup">
  <li tabindex="0" class="radio" checked>
    Water
  </li>
  <li tabindex="-1" class="radio">
    Tea
  </li>
  <li tabindex="-1" class="radio">
    Coffee
  </li>
  <li tabindex="-1" class="radio">
    Cola
  </li>
  <li tabindex="-1" class="radio">
    Ginger Ale
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: HTML is not a programming language, it is just a way of writing exactly like you would write on a piece of paper you can add to it take from it without the paper screaming at  you **That's wrong**

Comment: Asking for an off-site resource is, unfortunately, specifically off-topic for Stack Overflow questions, because of the inherent transience of 'best.' The easiest way to find a resource about attributes would be to use the search engine of your choice and search for terms such as "*valid attributes for* <element-type>" - I'd suggest adding the term "*MDN*" in order to reduce the number of results and to remove the likelihood of finding w3schools (which has nothing to do with the [W3](https://W3.org)).

Comment: My apologies, I just noticed I incorrectly referred to W3 Schools as W3C in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are required to do the best they can with whatever markup is given to them. That means handling this invalid attribute. Yes, it is invalid and not allowed on `<li>` tags.

[The HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#attr-input-checked)

> The checked content attribute is a boolean attribute that gives the
>   default checkedness of the input element.

Comment: "*Yes, it is invalid and not allowed on `<li>` tags.*" - while I agree, the answer would be improved by citing your source(s).

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica The HTML standard should be assumed but I will look it up.

Comment: @Rob  The checked attribute altho is invalid, it can be accessed through javascript and put a value on it with setAttribute

Comment: @GeorgePaouris Invalid is still invalid and should not be used that way. *The checked content attribute is a boolean attribute that gives the default checkedness of the input element.*

Answer (score 0):

You can find that type of information on MDN Web Docs. For example, after looking that the documentation for the [HTML Element `<li>` Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#Attributes)

**TLDR;**

The `<li>` tag has its own attributes as well as inherits the global attributes (i.e style, class, id, etc..) that is special to it which is the value attribute.

`<li>` attributes:

- value
- type

Global Attributes can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of all attributes and their supported tags on W3 schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_attributes.asp

While `<li checked></li>` would be invalid, you could use custom data attributes if you want to apply a checked state to a list item for use with Javascript. For custom data attributes, see the following:
https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/